# Deploy laravel apache (public access forbidden)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I deploy laravel project on apache web server and this is my .conf

[this is my conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDyrB.png)

and in my public_html I've 4 project

[list of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0LU9.png)

but when i go to mydomain.com/sso_NAP (for example) my browser show this error
[error when i put /public in my conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUvu8.png)

need help

Comment: Code is _text_, so please post as _text_, _not_ as an image.

Comment: did you try restarting the server after the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Some Options parameters need the +/- syntax

Change:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

to:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

Comment: still forbidden :(

Answer (score 0):

if it is in linux/ubuntu, have you checked the directory permissions?

I had the same problem with my project in ubuntu, the solution in my case:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data laravel-project/ && sudo chmod -R g+rw laravel-project/
```